# Chemicals in a Rubber Compound - NSR 20, Accel CS, Accel DPG, Anitiox Q, Antioz PMB

Tags: polymers

I have a recipe for a rubber compound and am trying to understand some of the ingredients.

The ones I do not recognize are

Compound A

- NSR 20
- Accel CS
- Accel DPG
- Anitiox Q
- Antioz PMB

Compound B

- SMR 20
- Accel NS
- Accel DPG
- PVI

Compound C

- Orox HR
- Orac CS
- Orac TMTD

Is there a place to look these up on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSR 20 and SMR 20 are natural rubber (Nigerian Standard Rubber and [Standard Malaysian Rubber](http://www.klpk.com.my/content/display/article/site:klpk-param:standard_malaysian_rubber-link:7546))

"Accel" and "Orac" mean accelerator.

Accel DPG is diphenyl guanidine.

"Antiox" and "orox" mean antioxidant

"Antioz" means antiozonant

"Orac CS" is likely N-cyclohexyl-2-benzothiazole sulphenamide

"Orac TMTD" is likely Tetramethylthiuram disulfide

"PVI" may refer to pre-vulcanization inhibitor

Comment: Dave. This helps a lot. Do you know if "Orac" and "Orox" are industry terms? Could Antiox PMB be p-methoxybenzyl?

Comment: I don't think "Orac" and "Orox" are industry-wide terms.  Different companies use different names for the same compound.  If you looked through catalogs of chemical companies that see rubber antioxidants, antiozonant,  accelerators, etc. you might find more information.